# SQL: Linking a Count to a specific value through multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to link a COUNT to a specific value across several tables in a SQL Server Database. In this case the tables only share values through correlation. I am returning the values I want but the COUNT is counting everything in a given project not just the ones linked to their work items.

```
        SELECT 
            [d].[Id]
            ,COUNT([t].[ItemId]) AS ItemCount
            ,[d].[ItemName]
        FROM
          [dbo].[Project_Map] [rm] WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN
          [dbo].[WorkProjects] [r] WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON  [r].[DomainId] = [rm].[DomainId]
            AND [r].[ProjectId] = [rm].[ProjectId]
            AND [r].[ReleaseId] = [rm].[ReleaseId]
        INNER JOIN
          [dbo].[Items] [d] WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON  [d].[DomainId] = [r].[DomainId]
            AND [d].[ProjectId] = [r].[ProjectId]
            AND [d].[ReleaseId] = [r].[ReleaseId]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Projects] [p] with (NOLOCK)
        ON r.DomainId = p.DomainId
        AND r.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tests] [t] with (NOLOCK)
        ON p.DomainId = t.DomainId
        AND p.ProjectId = t.ProjectId
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT [Id], MAX([LastModifiedDate]) AS MostRecent
            FROM Items 
            Group By [Id]
        ) AS updatedItem
        ON updatedItem.Id = d.Id
        INNER JOIN
          [dbo].[WorkItemStates] [ds] WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON  [ds].[ItemStateName] = [d].[ItemStatus]
        WHERE 
          d.Id = 111111 
          AND d.UserCategory Like 'SOMESTRING'
        GROUP BY d.Id, d.ItemName
```

RETURNS: In this case the count should be 1 but it returns the count for the entire project.

```
            ID    COUNT ITEMNAME
            86    5169  SOME NAME
            173   5169  SOME NAME
            170   5169  SOME NAME
```

Am I missing a join somewhere?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: hard to tell with this much information, but from the experience I can tell that you are probably not missing a join but missing a clause in one of the ON conditions of a join...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your counts are counting all `JOIN` instances and not just distinct *Item* level records. Consider turning your *Item* unit level join into an aggregate query join and include the count field in outer grouping:

Specifically, change:

```
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tests] [t] with (NOLOCK)
        ON p.DomainId = t.DomainId
        AND p.ProjectId = t.ProjectId
```

Into:

```
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT t.DomaindId, t.ProjectId, Count(*) As ItemCount
     FROM [dbo].[Tests] t
     GROUP BY t.DomaindId, t.ProjectId) agg
ON p.DomainId = agg.DomainId
AND p.ProjectId = agg.ProjectId
```

And then the outer query structure becomes:

```
SELECT 
     [d].[Id]
     ,agg.ItemCount
     ,[d].[ItemName]
FROM 
   ...
GROUP BY 
     [d].[Id]
     ,agg.ItemCount
     ,[d].[ItemName]
```

Interestingly, you already do such an aggregate query join but never use that derived table *updateItem* or the field *MostRecent*.